# WxWidgets CheckListBox getting value issue

Tags: wxwidgets, checklistbox

I have a problem with WxWidgets version 3.0.2. Currently I'm trying to get the value of a 'ChecklistBox' with index number 0.

It seems to work, however I can't get it to fill a string variable from C++.

I tried a lot of things, such as .ToString(), .mb_str(), (string)varname, etc.

The code I am using to get the value which I presume works, but returns a non 'string' result, so I can't use it in my C++ code... (at least not yet..)

The Code I use to get the value of index number 0 returns no errors:

```
CheckListBox = new wxCheckListBox(this, CHECKBOX1, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(208,63), 0, 0, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("CHECKBOX1"));
CheckListBox->GetItem(0); //Seems to work (at least gives no errors)

String Test = CheckListBox->GetItem(0); //Fails
```

***Error returned: conversion from ‘wxOwnerDrawn*’ to non-scalar type std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}|***

Simple test such as the following work since I see 'Test' added to the CheckListBox:

```
CheckListbox->Check(CheckListBox->Append("Test"));
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried .mb_str().data()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see `GetItem(idx)` in `CheckListBox`.

Perhaps you are looking for `virtual wxString   GetString (unsigned int n) const` which is inherited from `wxListBox`.

Comment: Thanks, GetString was the way to go

Comment: Upvote and/or accept the answer is the normal way to thank someone who has helped you.

Comment: Sure, but you need at least 15 reputation john

Comment: I was under the impression you could accept an answer without special rep, but I won't argue.

Comment: Accept yes, I did actually